# Cosmos DB Composite Key based on EF Predicate Query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a very simple EF query to retrieve data from Cosmos DB. I would like to add a composite key based on the query from EF. I can add a composite key based on normal SQL queries in cosmos which works perfectly fine, however, when it comes to EF queries the same technique doesn't work.

```
private readonly IRepository<AdministratorResolutionApproved> _repository;
public Administrator_Resolutions_Approved_List_GET(IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        _repository = repositoryFactory.RepositoryOf<AdministratorResolutionApproved>();
    }

public async Task GetDataAsync(){

Expression<Func<AdministratorResolutionApproved, bool>> predicate = = item => item.Pk == "key-approved" && item.Ttl == -1;

var result = await _repository.GetAsync(predicate);
}
```

**Comos Query**

```
{"query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (((root[\"pk\"] = \"key-approved\") AND (root[\"ttl\"] = -1)) AND ((NOT IS_DEFINED(root[\"type\"])) OR (root[\"type\"] = \"AdministratorResolutionApproved\")))"}
```

I added the following composite key in the cosmos settings but didn't work for the query.

**Composite Index in Azure**

```
"compositeIndexes": [
        [
            {
                "path": "/pk",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/ttl",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/type",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

If I write a SQL statement and execute it from Data Explorer in the Azure portal, I see a big difference in both performance and RUs cost between the queries.

**Normal SQL query which composite key works**

```
SELECT * FROM c 
where c.pk = "key-approved"
and c.ttl = -1
and c.type = "AdministratorResolutionApproved"
```

So How I can add the composite keys based on the predicate?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the cost is different is because these are not equivalent queries.

The addition of the system function IS_DEFINED with an OR on the filter predicate is likely causing the query engine to not use the composite index. You might try creating a second composite index without the type property and see if that helps. If the performance does not improve, then IS_DEFINED itself may prevent the query engine from using the composite index.

PS: temporarily turning on index metrics is often helpful when troubleshooting query performance [Indexing metrics in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/index-metrics). But I don't think you can enable these from EF. You'll have to use the native Cosmos DB .NET SDK to do it.